# delay callback doesn't work with hide event

Tags: jquery

```
$("#myDiv").delay("3000").fadeOut("1000",function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
```

The div hide directly after 3 sec, it doesn't fade Out.. why?

Comment: fadeOut() hides the content, you dont need callback there...

Comment: even though `hide()` is not required.. it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DrUFm/1/

Comment: I'm guessing it's a positioning issue. The code posted works just fine, but jQuery can sometimes have issues with fading elements placed in a certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use like this:

```
$("#myDiv").delay("3000").fadeOut("1000");
```

No need to use `$(this).hide()` in the callback as `fadeOut("1000")` do what you want.